# Failure to precompile assets for production - rails/webpacker/react/redux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, webpack, redux

I am new to web development and I've been working on this website using rails/webpacker/react/redux. I am trying to deploy a website on heroku but am unable to precompile assets for production. I am not sure where to start looking... any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       yarn install v1.16.0
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning " > @babel/preset-react@7.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-self@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@7.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
       warning " > react-addons-css-transition-group@15.6.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.4.2".
       warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
       warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 25.09s.
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.897956 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-brands-400-c563adbadc5eafb6708b610268fbd393d59ae41e220aae5aac99ca2d45a6e151.eot
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.898552 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-brands-400-c563adbadc5eafb6708b610268fbd393d59ae41e220aae5aac99ca2d45a6e151.eot.gz
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.902918 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-regular-400-6e70525bb429041c5ec84a81cf4733303cee90966809ed255741fa50e123ae47.eot
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.903545 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-regular-400-6e70525bb429041c5ec84a81cf4733303cee90966809ed255741fa50e123ae47.eot.gz
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.910497 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-solid-900-c141af323058f12f8b0bc760162f9928f6a415fa04940b486fdb4086284e6ecf.eot
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.911418 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-solid-900-c141af323058f12f8b0bc760162f9928f6a415fa04940b486fdb4086284e6ecf.eot.gz
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.925980 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-brands-400-f6ae6226846422df4abf64b65814d3ccd3570af5e0350983fdb01fbc0dd055d6.svg
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.927785 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-brands-400-f6ae6226846422df4abf64b65814d3ccd3570af5e0350983fdb01fbc0dd055d6.svg.gz
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.934279 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-regular-400-a849aa4ab8a20512c2e073ed66cf146c5615220c74da85c10909eb2c33d3317a.svg
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.935238 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-regular-400-a849aa4ab8a20512c2e073ed66cf146c5615220c74da85c10909eb2c33d3317a.svg.gz
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.954168 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-solid-900-7ad9caabf64ee35d113612f7bb10e531fb17ab431a51e0b088e93f89e1915549.svg
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.955542 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-solid-900-7ad9caabf64ee35d113612f7bb10e531fb17ab431a51e0b088e93f89e1915549.svg.gz
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.961066 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-brands-400-3b3fbc59f287f33a3870175b19eb94d7cbb546af2fdbab29df91ba834352d3ea.ttf
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.971472 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-brands-400-3b3fbc59f287f33a3870175b19eb94d7cbb546af2fdbab29df91ba834352d3ea.ttf.gz
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.985214 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-regular-400-418571014c9250c6197fc3ac4e8e5d96d7a49711a5d6308ca0d36b6f3045c611.ttf
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.985645 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-regular-400-418571014c9250c6197fc3ac4e8e5d96d7a49711a5d6308ca0d36b6f3045c611.ttf.gz
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.992705 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-solid-900-cef5dd667be89aa0b9d1bd0a2ceb7c017c7b183f81d0213f8f99bd380f042577.ttf
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:51.993679 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-solid-900-cef5dd667be89aa0b9d1bd0a2ceb7c017c7b183f81d0213f8f99bd380f042577.ttf.gz
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:52.002024 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-brands-400-ca734c792a24c20ff91ec878fd146b3354d4859f728f481c1089a3e2ffa2d30f.woff
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:52.013422 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-regular-400-9064839b35308c034ecf20f0335ea37331328d962baff8e589e69d01f5a56ffe.woff
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:52.022468 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-solid-900-1675e164e5ec88e30fb8c912cf9343c06c18fe419663b40de0a3bf92371b1d07.woff
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:52.026327 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-brands-400-c885e9f2017a2ed7075db9e876d40a04aa3208114443803bdb120a34afd3b1d6.woff2
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:52.030745 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-regular-400-e5c1d9e7bdeaf3372dee724d175d25aca879ed52ae9afd018f503e9d74e09b50.woff2
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:52.046853 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/font-awesome/fa-solid-900-08aa3a5ee68a21d5771a70b20495b6da1c0f996c46982cd1b0447ad2db730d11.woff2
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:52.051358 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/logo-7503965f57527ed84af8d8e378fbd4eac363d7c2957087df25708a271702bb5f.png
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:53.190381 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/application-c0f898962791bbeb2c3d9ecc3d06f92712a9140ac95df7a5df1e49734a84f0ec.js
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:53.190749 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/application-c0f898962791bbeb2c3d9ecc3d06f92712a9140ac95df7a5df1e49734a84f0ec.js.gz
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:53.193892 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/README-b1a3cc3c48f8a1a0f33b1e796b0c673ecca067c6ce0478a2e6b7743a82aaf644.md
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:54.955033 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/application-914724c57f90c908409a2348534a1b490dd732192748c57379b6a5e198833283.css
       I, [2019-07-30T19:26:54.955212 #1773]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_dffa9f95caf630c57973decfff8e4f94/public/assets/application-914724c57f90c908409a2348534a1b490dd732192748c57379b6a5e198833283.css.gz
       Compiling…
       Compilation failed:
```

Comment: This looks like the error output.  On its own, it's impossible for us to determine what's wrong.  Post your source, preferably a reduced to the minimum needed to reproduce the error.  That'll let us help you get this sorted out.

Comment: Hi, I was able to fix the problem with GProst's help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try to run `RAILS_ENV=production bin/bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on your **local** machine. If it works for you locally then most likely the compilation fails due to the lack of memory on your Heroku instance.
In that case, you could, for example, compile those assets for production on some machine with a relatively big amount of memory end then simply deploy the compiled files to Heroku server

Also, try setting `webpack_compile_output: true` in `webpacker.yml` to be able to see detailed info

Comment: I tried it and this is what I got:

RAILS_ENV=production bin/bundle exec rake assets:precompile
yarn install v1.17.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.41s.
Compiling…
Compilation failed:

Comment: Thanks! with your advice, I was able to get assets to precompile locally and I get a warning message regarding exceeding asset/entry point size limit. I tried deploying on heroku again but it fails to compile there.

Comment: Then don't compile it there but instead deploy compiled assets directly

Comment: It finally deployed to heroku successfully but still experiencing errors. Now I am getting 

ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application in /app/public/packs/manifest.json

Comment: I added public/assets to git and deployed it, which contains a manifest.json prefixed with sprockets, and I can see application.js in it...

Comment: I renamed that file to manifest.json and everything works now but that's obviously not the best way to solve this problem. Thank you for all your help!!